# defining and activating my wifi for lenovo b5400 for noob

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, lenovo

i'm really new to ubuntu and really excited about it. 
i've bought a lenovo b5400 and installed 12.04 version of ubuntu.
checked several forums and could not find the answer for:

how to activate my wifi card?

all answers will be appreciated,

Joe

Update1: running lspci | grep Network command got:

horim@horim:~$ lspci | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b723

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Start by opening a terminal (ctrl + alt + t) and typing  `lspci | grep Network`. Copy the line relevant to your wifi adapter and edit your question with this info to permit people to give you relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the drivers section and activate the driver. But as far as I'm concerned you'll need an Internet connection to install it (i.e. LAN). At least that worked for me, but I use Ubuntu GNOME 13.10

Why do you want to install Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: I believe i've tried activating the drivers and updated them all via lan.
perhaps i did something the wrong way? i'm not sure. if there are any step by step recommendations on how to deal with it, i'd be happy to hear.

ubuntu 12.04 just cause i've had a wee bit more experience with it.