# Activate/deactivate Wi-Fi on Lenovo B5400 under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, lenovo

I have a Lenovo B5400 with Ubuntu 14.04 x64. The ethernet port works fine. How can I enable/disable the wifi connection? I have no hardware button for this functionality. Under Windows I can press Fn+F5 and a dialog window appears, but I cannot find this functionality under Linux.

`lspci | grep Network` produces:

> 04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

The answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437684/defining-and-activating-my-wifi-for-lenovo-b5400-for-noob) is incomplete; any other idea?

Thanks.

**Later edit:**
The output of `rfkill list all` is:

> 0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
>       Soft blocked: yes
>       Hard blocked: yes

1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty trick worked: I booted the machine in Windows and started the wifi from Fn+F5 combination; note that this works in windows only when HotKey Intergration Driver  is installed from lenovo site.

The main question is: what if one gets the laptop w/o Windows, e.g. free dos or linux pre-installed?

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off your wifi using `iwconfig`.
To do that open a terminal and type the following command:

```
iwconfig wlan0 down
```

That should turn off your wifi.
To turn it on you can use:

```
iwconfig wlan0 up
```

You can also turn it on/off using the wireless settings menu.
Go to system setings → network → wireless. There you can turn it on/off.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I press on the on/off button you highlighted in the last picture, the button remains on the off position. Any clue?

Comment: please post the output of `rfkill list all`

Comment: Added as later edit for the question.